# With ggplot in R, plot data in different color scales depending on one variable

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have a set of 12 time-series, everyone identified by a series_no, stored in a variable called "series". Also I have three classes and every series corresponds to one of these classes, such information is recorded in a categorical variable called "class". For instance:

```r
 series  ts                      value    class
 1       2023-04-01 11:00:00     3        A
 3       2023-04-01 11:00:00     53       A
 5       2023-04-01 11:00:00     4        C
[...]
```

I want to plot all these series in one plot but each series should have a different color and intensity of the color depending on the class it belongs to. Let's say for instance that class A goes in green, so series 1 which belongs to class A could be in light green, series 3 which also belongs to class A could be in dark green; class C could go in blue, so series 5 should be light blue, and so on.

I guess setting a different color scale for each class could help, but I don't know how to do this.

I don't mind to split my data in three different dataframes if that helps to plot the data differently.

Comment: Possible duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/q/77888109/903061

Comment: You might also do this by specifying `alpha=as.factor(series)` in your `aes()`

Comment: Finally I got it using the [ggnewscalelibrary](https://github.com/eliocamp/ggnewscale) and creating a new geom_line for each class with a specific df. To set the colors, I had to define my own vector of colors like c("green", "darkgreen", etc) and use scale_color_manual function after every geom_line. Something like:
```geom_line(data = df.A, aes(x = ts, y = value, col = series)) +
  scale_color_manual(values = oranges, name = "class A") +
  new_scale_color() +
  geom_line(data = df.B, aes(x = ts, y = value, col = series), ) + 
  scale_color_manual(values = greens, name = "class B")```